# .next() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<span class="retrievedValue"><%= f.text_field :DIRECT_LABEL, :class=>"mandatory", :onblur =>"validate_this_textfield(this.value, this.id);" %></span>
<span style="display: none; float: left;"> <img src="../images/green_tick.png" /></span>
```

I need to display the 'green_tick.png' image when user fills in the field. For this I used the javascript function below:

```
function validate_this_textfield(field_value, field_id)
{
    if( $j('#' + field_id).val() != "") {

        $j('#' + field_id ).next().show(); // show next element after field
    }
    else{
        $j('#' + field_id ).next().hide();
    }
}
```

I am using ' .next().show(); ' to show the 'green_tick.png' image, but it does not seem to work.

Any suggestion??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
function validate_this_textfield(field_value, field_id)
{
    if( $j('#' + field_id).val() != "") {
        $j('#' + field_id ).removeClass('mandatory');
        $j('#' + field_id ).addClass('mandatory_field_completed')
        .parent().next().show(); // show next element after field
    }
    else{
        $j('#' + field_id ).removeClass('mandatory_field_completed');
        $j('#' + field_id ).addClass('mandatory')
        .parent().next().hide();
    }
}
```

You want to get the next from the span, not the field inside the span, so you need to go to the parent first.

Answer (score 1):

According to jQuery API docs, the `next` method:

> Gets the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

The `<img>` tag isn't the sibling of your field. You would have to do something like this:

```
$('#fieldID').parent().next().show();
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wWeyj/

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the span first before using `.next()` as the span is a sibling of the

```
<span class="retrievedValue"> and not the input itself try this..
```

So add this to your selector..   `.closest('.retrievedValue')`

```
function validate_this_textfield(field_value, field_id)
{
    if( $j('#' + field_id).val() != "") {
        $j('#' + field_id ).removeClass('mandatory');
        $j('#' + field_id ).addClass('mandatory_field_completed')
        .closest('.retrievedValue').next().show(); // show next element after field
    }
    else{
        $j('#' + field_id ).removeClass('mandatory_field_completed');
        $j('#' + field_id ).addClass('mandatory')
        .closest('.retrievedValue').next().hide();
    }
}
```